# Can I alias a key in an object literal?

Tags: javascript-objects, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

I have an object literal which is used as a configuration element and is looked up for keys.

```
customRendering:{
                  key1: func(){....},
                  key2: func(){....}
}
```

I have a situation where `key2` and `key3` can use the same function. Is there a way to assign the same function to both `key2` and `key3` without having to declare the function outside the object literal and without having to declare an extra key?

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
key2: key3: func(){....}
```

Comment: key2 and key3 are the same there is no need for having 2 keys

Comment: @Ibu, not necessarily, creating an object for a particular interface or API may require having values defined to `key1` and `key2`.

Comment: I'm not sure why is this question marked as a duplicate, it is actually  not. Declaring properties aliases is not the same as making self-references within object declaration.
For aliases there is quite useful util: [split-keys](https://www.npmjs.org/package/split-keys).
With that tool you can gracefully declare properties as a list of keys.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### A safe way:

I don't know what I was thinking earlier. If you're fine with using a more verbose "literal" you can instantiate a custom function:

```
o = new function () {
  this.foo = function () { console.log('works'); };
  this.bar = this.foo;
};
```

### This is a dirty nasty hack:

you *could* use a temporary variable to store the reference to the function while setting the object. Be careful to use a closure and to call `var` before using it so that you don't pollute the global namespace:

```
(function () {
  var o, baz;
  o = {
    foo: baz = function () {console.log('works')},
    bar: baz
  }
  //more code
}());
```

The reason I'm calling this a dirty nasty hack is that it makes the code less readable, it's harder to tell examining this code (especially if the object literal declaration was longer) *where* `baz` was set.

Better to just write the alias outside the object literal so that it's explicitly visible that it is an alias.

**Note:** the named function format *doesn't work*:

```
o = { //THIS WON'T WORK
  foo: function baz() {/* code */},
  bar: baz
}
```

---

<del>There's no way within an object literal to define an alias using a shared reference.</del>

You *can* use an aliasing function, but it wont be an identical reference:

```
o = {
  foo: function...
  bar: function () { return this.foo() } //even better if you use `apply` or `call`
}
```

The typical way to share a reference is after the object literal, which sounds like what you wanted to avoid:

```
o = {
  foo: function...
}
o.bar = o.foo;
```

Alternatively as you pointed out in your question (and for completeness) you could define the function outside of the object literal:

```
func = function () {/* code */};
o = {
  foo: func,
  bar: func
}
```

<sub>In response to @Peter about returning an object from a function</sub>

Using a self-executing anonymous function is *another* way of instantiating an object inline, and would make this entire question moot:

```
o = (function () {
  var o = {
    foo: function () {/*code*/}
  }
  o.bar = o.foo;
  return o;
}());
```

Or like this:

```
var o = (function () {
  var shared = function() { console.log("shared") };
  return {
    foo: shared,
    bar: shared
  }
}());
```

Comment: +1 I would definitely use apply or call

Comment: I like your first code snippet, although I would probably make the anonymous function return the object itself. This way it becomes very explicit what variable is being set.

Comment: @Peter, which anonymous function? The wrapping closure is purely for preventing variables from leaking into global scope.

Comment: @zzzzBov, I meant like this: `var obj = (function() { var baz; return { /*...*/ } })();`

Comment: @Peter, I've updated my answer to respond to that particular technique of instantiating an object.

Comment: @zzzzBov Cool, I like it. Let me just make a couple tweaks, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

> without having to declare the function outside the object literal

I think this part makes it impossible.  However, while I use JavaScript all the time, I am not a professional JS ninja, so perhaps I am wrong.

Code for how I would do this (although it seems you already know you can do this, I thought it might be best to say it anyway):

```
customRendering = {};
customRendering.key1 = func(){....};
customRendering.key2 = customRendering.key1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Define the function aside from the object:

```
var func = function() { ... };
...
  customRendering: {
    key1: func,
    key2: func
  }
```

Comment: -1 Going to quote the question here. "Is there a way to assign the same function to both key2 and key3 without having to declare the function outside the object literal"

Answer (score -3):

Sorry I understood your question incorrectly.

Here is a possible solution:

```
    var obj = {
      func1: function() {},
      func2: obj.func1
    }
```

Comment: It wont work for me. In my case 'obj' is embedded in a self-invocated function and so 'this' doesn't refer to obj.

Comment: Sorry, I put this by mistake there. I changed "this" with actual object variable name.

Comment: That code wont work. `obj` will be `undefined` until after the construction using the object literal, meaning that when the object literal is called. `obj.func1` will be trying to call `func1` on `undefined`, which will create an error.